# R function prints variable but reports that object <variable> not found

Tags: r

I'm making a series of nested function calls and seeing some unusual behavior which I can't reproduce with a simple example, so the original code is as follows:

```
source("DataManager.R")
x <- getQuotesFromService('JNJ', '2016-04-01', '2016-05-10')
```

and get the following output:

```
getQuotesFromService parameters:
 sDate= 2016-04-01 , eDate= 2016-05-10 , service= finance.yahoo 
getQuotesFromService USING FINANCE.YAHOO SERVICE:
 sDate= 2016-04-01 , eDate= 2016-05-10 , service= finance.yahoo 
1 getDateRanges params: startDate= 2016-04-01 | endDate= 2016-05-10
```

followed by this error message:

```
Error in cat("1 getDateRanges params: startDate=", startDate, "| endDate=",  : 
object 'startDate' not found
```

which is generated from this code:

```
getQuotesFromService <- function(ticker, sDate, eDate, service="finance.yahoo") {
library(XML)
cat("getQuotesFromService parameters:\n",
    "sDate=", sDate, ", eDate=", eDate, ", service=", service, "\n")
quotes <- NULL
if(service == "finance.yahoo") {
    source('YahooQuotes.R')
    cat("getQuotesFromService USING FINANCE.YAHOO SERVICE:\n",
        "sDate=", sDate, ", eDate=", eDate, ", service=", service, "\n")
    dateRanges <- getDateRanges(sDate, eDate, 360, 10)
    quotes <- getMultipleYqlQuotes(dateRanges)
}

return(quotes)
}
```

which call this function:

```
getDateRanges <- function(startDate, endDate,
                      daysInInterval=360,
                      maxAllowableYears=10) {
  cat('1 getDateRanges params: startDate=', startDate,
      '| endDate=', endDate, '\n')

  ## MORE STUFF HERE, BUT GETS EXECUTED AFTER POINT OF ERROR ##

}
```

What puzzles me is that the **startDate** get printed out in the call to **cat** in **getDateRanges**, but R is telling me that **object 'startDate' is not found**.

Any ideas as to why I'm seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are not correctly passing the output of `getDateRanges` to `getDateRanges`.

Try something like the following:

```
quotes <- getMultipleYqlQuotes("startDate"=dateRanges[1], "endDate"=dateRanges[2])
```

You can pass a vector of the start and end dates to `getMultipleYqlQuotes`, but in the body of the function you would have to refer to the elements of the vector. If you use the above method, you won't have to rewrite this.